# How to break sentences to get clear understanding?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, reading

> Sparva, unlike Treland’s other provinces, requires automobile insurers to pay for any medical treatment sought by someone who has been involved in an accident; in the other provinces, insurers pay for nonemergency treatment only if they pre-approve the treatment. **Clearly, Sparva’s less restrictive policy must be the explanation for the fact that altogether insurers there pay for far more treatments after accidents than insurers in other provinces, even though Sparva does not have the largest population.**

My understanding of this passage:
*First sentence:* Insurers in Sparva are paying for medical treatment, but not paying in other provinces.
*Second sentence:* Insurers in Sparva pay for far more treatments.
Here I have difficulty in understanding, because in first sentence person is demanding for paying, but in second sentence saying insurers are paying far more for treatment.

It is really confusing...........

Comment: Note the difference is in Sparva '**any medical treatment** sought by someone who has been involved in an accident', where as in other provinces 'insurers pay for **nonemergency treatment only** if they preapprove the treatment'

Comment: But both are talking about accident's treatment............

Comment: But  the difference is **emergency treatment** is excluded in other regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The writer in the paragraph is trying to explain how and why automobile insurers in Sparva have to pay for far more treatments after accidents compared to any other province in Treland.

I think, what the paragraph is trying to convey is that:

In Sparva, automobile insurers pay for any medical treatment that is sought by someone who has been involved in an accident. Even if the treatment sought by that person is a nonemergency treatment, insurers in Sparva still have to pay for it.

This is not the case in Treland's other provinces, where insurers pay for nonemergency services only if they preapprove them. That's why insurers in Sparva pay for more treatments than Treland's any other province.